# How to convert Mat On OpenCV to be of type CV_16UC1

Tags: opencv

Tried imread parameters, and tried convertTo with different type. 
Didn't work.
Do you  know how it can be done?

Comment: What is you input? Have you tried *input.convertTo(output, CV_16U)*?

Comment: How exactly do you know it isn't working?

Comment: My input is read from jpeg, and as I said I tried convert. I'm getting type 16

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to make sure that the source mat is also a single channel mat. Then you can do like this.

```
cv::Mat newMat;
oldMat.convertTo(newMat, CV_16UC1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting this line from [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto):

> rtype – desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth since the number of channels are the same as the input has; if rtype is negative, the output matrix will have the same type as the input.

Also bear in mind that the different matrix types have different ranges of values they can store - scaling with alpha (3rd parameter) can help resolve this. [Here's a list of the types and their properties](http://ninghang.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html) (it took me way too long to find one when I was looking, so there you go, just in case).